# How to Add Child on Firebase and then Get it and Display the information?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to understand Firebase and I've been reading the useless Docs and looking on Here but none seem to help me understand the basics of adding and displaying from Firebase. I'm trying to add a Child to Salesperson containing the name and number of cars sold so I can then retrieve them and display them on a table.

```
var salespersonRef = database.ref('Salespersons');

  $("#add-user").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    name = $("#name-input").val().trim();
    cars_sold = $("#cars_sold-input").val().trim();

    salespersonRef.child({
      name: name,
      cars_sold: cars_sold,
    });


 salespersonRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {

    // Log everything that's coming out of snapshot
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    console.log(snapshot.val().name);
    console.log(snapshot.val().cars_sold);
    // Change the HTML to reflect
    $("#name-display").text(snapshot.val().name);
    $("#cars_sold-display").text(snapshot.val().cars_sold);
```

So thats what I have at the moment for adding and displaying. It does display the current addition but it overwrites anything I add and doesnt make another child

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't do anything:

```
salespersonRef.child({
  name: name,
  cars_sold: cars_sold,
});
```

If you're trying to add a new child under `salespersonRef`, it should be:

```
salespersonRef.push({
  name: name,
  cars_sold: cars_sold,
});
```

Every time you can `push()` it generates a new unique location under that reference.

Comment: Yeah, That was my current code just messing around trying to figure it out, Thank you btw. How do I display the unique keys now?

Comment: You're probably looking for `snapshot.forEach(...)` as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events.